# LibreOffice Calc - Number of occurrences in text string

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I'm sorry if this has been asked already, but I haven't found the answer.

I'm looking for a formula or combination thereof that can count the number of occurrences/repetitions in a text string. For example, if cell A1 contains "XYZXYZ", I would like to search cell A1 for "XYZ" and have "2" as a result (because "XYZ" occurs 2 times in A1).

`={find.repetitions}(A1;"XYZ") --> 2`

If B1 contains "Mary is my friend but Mary doesn't like roses":

`={find.repetitions}(B1;"Mary") --> 2`

I tried fiddling with the FIND and SEARCH functions, but they only give me the position of the first occurence. The COUNTIF function can only count entire matching cells within a range, which is not what I'm looking for. I would specifically like to count occurrences of a text snippet within a single cell (single text string).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: So, in every case the repeated element is constantly "XYZ"?

Comment: If the cell says "XYZABCXYZ", the result should also be 2.
If the cell says "XAYBZC", the result should be 0.

Comment: OK, i think this would require a macro, AFAIK there's no single formula or combination to achieve this.

Answer (score 5):

A friend of mine came up with the answer!

If A1 contains "XYZ how many times does XYZ occur XYZ?" and A2 contains "XYZ", then the function

`=(len(A1)-len(substitute(A1;A2;"")))/len(A2)`

will produce `3`.

(question may be closed, I do not have enough points to do so).

Comment: so simple (-:
wonderfull trick ! thank you

Comment: `substitute(A1;A2;"")` should be `len(substitute(A1;A2;""))`

Answer (score 3):

The correct formula would be:

```
=(len(A1)-len(substitute(A1;A2;"")))/len(A2)
```

And it works perfectly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Dear Michele, thanks for your answer! However, best practice in that case was to correct the answer or suggest a correction, as Dave F did, instead of posting the correction as a fully new answer (which is not, ;)). I corrected the answer of Binz Nakama, thus, you might consider removing your, now, superfluous answer. Blessings.